# Multi-hosts use of virtualbox vdi disk

Tags: virtualbox, vdi

Can Virtualbox's vdi disk used together by the virtualbox in Windows and linux host? 
In my case, i am using virtualbox in windows os, the vdi is on storage server which is let me say Guaranteed will only be used by once at a time (because i am the only one using it). Sometimes, i need to access this vdi using the virtualbox, but from ubuntu host.

Is this possible? so sometimes, the vdi is used by virtualbox on linux, and then sometimes by ubuntu. The vdi itself contains upenSuse (server, text mode).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can run the same virtual machine in both operating systems without any changes.

But you should make sure that the VirtualBox version you use on the different platforms are not too different. This should not make a big difference but it may.

Another problematic feature (that you apparent  don't use) may be 3D acceleration because it may work slightly different of different platforms.

Comment: thanks, 3D acceleration won't be any issue. the quest OS is linux, text mode.

Answer (score 0):

have you checked this on virtualbox forum [Syncing VDI for use on multiple Hosts](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=43134)

it is usual talk that most of the visualization software uses same disk structure for these files and support for downgrade versions. have a look on the specified link to know more about the issues and other stuff..

hope this helps.